# Angular NgRx - Dispatch an Action N Times and Then Dispatch Success Action When All Completed

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx-effects

Part of my Angular app is creating Tasks for a project plan. The Tasks relate to moving items to different locations, think of chess pieces being moved on a board. The user selects 1 or more options from a list and then confirms their selection. The app needs to generate N Tasks (say, 4 for each option) to build the plan which will ultimately allow the user to see all the chess pieces being moved about. However, like with chess, after each batch of 4 Tasks are created (each user option) the Tasks must be saved to the NgRx Store triggering Selectors to update the configuration of the board because the next batch of Tasks being generated must consider the latest state of the board.

I have an array of user options. In a `TaskGenerationService` I iterate over the array dispatching Actions for each option. I have an Effect responding to the Actions and am using `concatMap` to enforce sequential handling of the Actions. Here's a simplified version:

```
  generateTaskCycle$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fromAppPlanActions.TasksGeneratorActions.generateTaskCycle),

      map(action => action.taskGenerationBundle),

      concatMap(taskGenerationBundle => of(taskGenerationBundle).pipe(

        // Get the selected data from the Store.
        concatLatestFrom(() => [
          this.store.select(fromAppPlanSelectors.taskSelectors.selectAllTasks),
          this.store.select(fromAppPlanSelectors.taskDependencySelectors.selectAllTaskDependencies),
          this.store.select(fromAppPlanSelectors.planSelectors.selectCurrentPlan),
        ]),

        map(([taskGenerationBundle, allTasks, allTaskDependencies, currentPlan]) => {

          // Check there is a currentPlan.
          if (currentPlan !== null) {

            // Get an array of the new Tasks to add to the Plan.
            const newTasksToAdd = this.taskGenerationService.createTasks(
              taskGenerationBundle.cycleId,
              taskGenerationBundle.fuelData,
              taskGenerationBundle.orderIdArray,
              taskGenerationBundle.parentTask,
              taskGenerationBundle.startDate,
            );

            // Get an array of TaskDependencies to add to the Plan.
            const newTaskDependenciesToAdd: TaskDependency[] = [];

            // Update the start and end dates on all Tasks and TaskDependencies.
            const updatedTasksAndTaskDependencies = this.taskService.addNewTasksAndTaskDependencies(
              newTasksToAdd,
              newTaskDependenciesToAdd,
              allTasks,
              allTaskDependencies,
              currentPlan
            );

            // Add the new Tasks and TaskDependencies to TaskGenerationService so we can add them to the API at the end of all cycles.
            this.taskGenerationService.allNewTasksToAdd.push(...newTasksToAdd);
            this.taskGenerationService.allNewTaskDependenciesToAdd.push(...newTaskDependenciesToAdd);

            // Dispatch an Action to upsert the updated Tasks and TaskDependencies in the Store.
            return fromAppPlanActions.TasksGeneratorActions.updateTasksAndTaskDependenciesInStore(
              { tasksAndTaskDependenciesToUpdate: updatedTasksAndTaskDependencies }
            );

          }
          else {

            // Dispatch an Action to warn the user that something went wrong.
            return fromAppPlanActions.TasksGeneratorActions.generateTasksFail(
              { errorMessage: 'Warning - Failed to generate Tasks. Could not get the current Plan.' }
            );

          };

        })
      )),

    )
  );
```

This appears to work but I cannot figure out how to dispatch an Action when all of the Tasks have been generated, when the `forEach` loop finishes dispatching Actions and the last call of the Effect finishes saving to the Store. I reason that I can't simply dispatch an Action after my `TaskGenerationService` ends the `forEach` loop as that has no concept of when the `concatMap` in my Effect has finished with the stream of Actions it is handling. I had thought of providing the `optionArrayLength` and `index` from the `forEach` loop with the data being passed to the Effect to try and check `if (index + 1 === optionArrayLength)` I must be at the final item, but I still need to dispatch the Action to save the last batch of Tasks to the Store.

I've been trying different approaches for a few days now and can't see the wood for the trees! Any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: It’s pretty complicated. I’d probably add an additional reducer listening to success actions and have that set a separate key in your state (batchSize maybe?). Then create an additional effect listening to the exact same action as your current effect listens to, and combine that stream with a latestFrom with a selector returning that batch size. If that hits your threshold, you can fire the action you need (which can also reset the batchSize again). Hope you understand what I mean..

Comment: Good suggestion thanks. Currently I am including the `optionArrayLength` and the `index` which I am using in the Effect to conditionally dispatch a `TaskGenerationSuccess` Action along with the final `updateTasksAndTaskDependenciesInStore` Action. It appears to work but I'm sure there's a better way.